# Validation accuracy zero and Loss is higher. Intent classification Using LSTM

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, text-classification, tf.keras

I'm trying to Build and LSTM model for intent classification using Tensorflow, Keras. But whenever I'm training the model with 30 or 40 epochs, my 1st 20 validation accuracy is zero and loss is more than accuracy. and if I try to change the code a little bit, validation accuracy is getting lower than Loss.

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
embedding (Embedding)        (None, 100, 16)           16000
_________________________________________________________________
bidirectional (Bidirectional (None, 64)                12544     
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 24)                1560
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 3)                 75
=================================================================
Total params: 30,179
Trainable params: 30,179
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Train on 200 samples, validate on 79 samples
```

```
loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy']
```

```
Epoch 1/40
2020-08-16 14:08:17.986786: W tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/implementation_selector.cc:310] Skipping optimization due to error while loading function libraries: Invalid argument: Functions '__inference___backward_standard_lstm_4932_5417' and '__inference___backward_standard_lstm_4932_5417_specialized_for_StatefulPartitionedCall_at___inference_distributed_function_6117' both implement 'lstm_6b97c168-2c7b-4dc3-93dd-5e68cddc574f' but their signatures do not match.
2020-08-16 14:08:20.550894: W tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/implementation_selector.cc:310] Skipping optimization due to error while loading function libraries: Invalid argument: Functions '__inference_standard_lstm_6338' and '__inference_standard_lstm_6338_specialized_for_sequential_bidirectional_forward_lstm_StatefulPartitionedCall_at___inference_distributed_function_7185' both implement 'lstm_62f19cc7-a1f0-447b-a17f-84a70fc095cd' but their signatures do not match.
200/200 - 10s - loss: 1.0798 - accuracy: 0.7850 - val_loss: 1.1327 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/40
200/200 - 1s - loss: 1.0286 - accuracy: 0.7850 - val_loss: 1.1956 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 3/40
200/200 - 1s - loss: 0.9294 - accuracy: 0.7850 - val_loss: 1.4287 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 4/40
200/200 - 1s - loss: 0.7026 - accuracy: 0.7850 - val_loss: 2.2190 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 5/40
200/200 - 1s - loss: 0.6183 - accuracy: 0.7850 - val_loss: 1.8499 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 6/40
200/200 - 1s - loss: 0.5980 - accuracy: 0.7850 - val_loss: 1.5809 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 7/40
200/200 - 1s - loss: 0.5927 - accuracy: 0.7850 - val_loss: 1.5118 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 8/40
200/200 - 1s - loss: 0.5861 - accuracy: 0.7850 - val_loss: 1.5711 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 9/40
200/200 - 1s - loss: 0.5728 - accuracy: 0.7850 - val_loss: 1.5106 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 10/40
200/200 - 1s - loss: 0.5509 - accuracy: 0.7850 - val_loss: 1.6389 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 11/40
200/200 - 1s - loss: 0.5239 - accuracy: 0.7850 - val_loss: 1.5991 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 12/40
200/200 - 1s - loss: 0.4860 - accuracy: 0.7850 - val_loss: 1.4903 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 13/40
200/200 - 1s - loss: 0.4388 - accuracy: 0.7850 - val_loss: 1.3937 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 14/40
200/200 - 1s - loss: 0.3859 - accuracy: 0.7850 - val_loss: 1.2329 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 15/40
200/200 - 1s - loss: 0.3460 - accuracy: 0.7850 - val_loss: 1.1700 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 16/40
200/200 - 1s - loss: 0.3323 - accuracy: 0.7850 - val_loss: 1.0077 - val_accuracy: 0.0127
Epoch 17/40
200/200 - 1s - loss: 0.3007 - accuracy: 0.8150 - val_loss: 1.2465 - val_accuracy: 0.2278
Epoch 18/40
200/200 - 0s - loss: 0.2752 - accuracy: 0.9200 - val_loss: 0.8890 - val_accuracy: 0.6329
Epoch 19/40
200/200 - 1s - loss: 0.2613 - accuracy: 0.9700 - val_loss: 0.9181 - val_accuracy: 0.6582
Epoch 20/40
200/200 - 1s - loss: 0.2447 - accuracy: 0.9600 - val_loss: 0.8786 - val_accuracy: 0.7468
Epoch 21/40
200/200 - 1s - loss: 0.2171 - accuracy: 0.9700 - val_loss: 0.7162 - val_accuracy: 0.8481
Epoch 22/40
200/200 - 1s - loss: 0.1949 - accuracy: 0.9700 - val_loss: 0.8051 - val_accuracy: 0.7848
Epoch 23/40
200/200 - 1s - loss: 0.1654 - accuracy: 0.9700 - val_loss: 0.4710 - val_accuracy: 0.8861
Epoch 24/40
200/200 - 1s - loss: 0.1481 - accuracy: 0.9700 - val_loss: 0.4209 - val_accuracy: 0.8861
Epoch 25/40
200/200 - 1s - loss: 0.1192 - accuracy: 0.9700 - val_loss: 0.3792 - val_accuracy: 0.8861
Epoch 26/40
200/200 - 1s - loss: 0.1022 - accuracy: 0.9700 - val_loss: 0.7279 - val_accuracy: 0.8101
Epoch 27/40
200/200 - 1s - loss: 0.0995 - accuracy: 0.9700 - val_loss: 1.3112 - val_accuracy: 0.6582
Epoch 28/40
200/200 - 1s - loss: 0.1161 - accuracy: 0.9650 - val_loss: 0.1435 - val_accuracy: 0.9747
Epoch 29/40
200/200 - 1s - loss: 0.0889 - accuracy: 0.9700 - val_loss: 0.3896 - val_accuracy: 0.8608
Epoch 30/40
200/200 - 1s - loss: 0.0830 - accuracy: 0.9700 - val_loss: 0.3840 - val_accuracy: 0.8608
Epoch 31/40
200/200 - 1s - loss: 0.0688 - accuracy: 0.9700 - val_loss: 0.3100 - val_accuracy: 0.9241
Epoch 32/40
200/200 - 1s - loss: 0.0611 - accuracy: 0.9700 - val_loss: 0.3524 - val_accuracy: 0.8987
Epoch 33/40
200/200 - 1s - loss: 0.0518 - accuracy: 0.9750 - val_loss: 0.4621 - val_accuracy: 0.8481
Epoch 34/40
200/200 - 1s - loss: 0.0457 - accuracy: 0.9900 - val_loss: 0.4344 - val_accuracy: 0.8481
Epoch 35/40
200/200 - 1s - loss: 0.0423 - accuracy: 0.9900 - val_loss: 0.4417 - val_accuracy: 0.8608
Epoch 36/40
200/200 - 1s - loss: 0.0372 - accuracy: 0.9900 - val_loss: 0.4701 - val_accuracy: 0.8481
Epoch 37/40
200/200 - 1s - loss: 0.0319 - accuracy: 0.9950 - val_loss: 0.3913 - val_accuracy: 0.8608
Epoch 38/40
200/200 - 1s - loss: 0.0309 - accuracy: 0.9950 - val_loss: 0.5739 - val_accuracy: 0.7975
Epoch 39/40
200/200 - 1s - loss: 0.0290 - accuracy: 0.9950 - val_loss: 0.5416 - val_accuracy: 0.8228
Epoch 40/40
200/200 - 1s - loss: 0.0292 - accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 0.3162 - val_accuracy: 0.8861
```

Comment: Can you please share your code so that we can help you. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There can be multiple reasons for the validation accuracy to be zero, you can check on these below things to make changes accordingly.

1. The samples you had taken are very less, train on 200 samples and validate on 79 samples, you can try increasing samples through some upsampling methods.
2. There is a possibility that there can be unseen data on validation and weights are not useful with unseen data.
   For example, if you have digits from 1-9 to classify, if you keep 1-7 for training and 8-9 for validation this data becomes an unseen scenario and `val_acc` will be 0.
   To fix this, shuffle the data before sending it to `model.fit`.
3. This can be a silly mistake, check if your validation data is mapped properly to its label.
   You can also give validation data explicitly like below.

> model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 32, nb_epoch=30,
> shuffle=True,verbose=1,callbacks=[remote, early_stopping],
> validation_data (X_validation, y_validation))